# shapes (127,1) and (13,) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 13 (dim 0)

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, score

i am try to find score of linear regression 
it gives me this type error my code is below

````
from sklearn import datasets
bostan=datasets.load_boston()

x=bostan.data
y=bostan.target

from sklearn import preprocessing

x_scale=preprocessing.scale(x)

yfrom sklearn import model_selection

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=model_selection.train_test_split(x_scale,)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

clf=LinearRegression()

clf.fit(x_train,y_train)

y_pred=clf.predict(x_test)

y_pred=y_pred.reshape(-1,1)

y_test=y_test.reshape(-1,1)


y=clf.score(y_pred,y_test)   # problem is in this line 
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `score` method of the classifier object does not work the way you are trying it to. You need to directly give `x_test` as input and that it will calculate `y_pred` on its own and give you the result with `y_test`. So, you do not need to reshape and the correct syntax would be:

```
y = clf.score(x_test, y_test)
```

If for any reason you need to calculate the score using y_pred then take a look at [sklearn.metrics](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics) module.

Comment: thank you its really help me a lot